# Sharepoint XSLT Filtering with Query from another list

Tags: sharepoint

I'm wanting to automatically have my list filter based on another list values. I'm just not sure how to retrieve the values from the list for filter. Does anybody have any examples where they are accessing another list to retrieve data for filtering there currently list.

Comment: You forgot to include any source XML (data) and the wanted result from processing it...

Comment: I have just a basic xslt data view webpart that displays the list on the screen nothing fancy. I have a database table that displays as a list in Sharepoint. That table has the permission on what data you are allowed to see the first list. So when the user navigates to the page the xslt would retrieve all the departments from the second list the the user has permissions to and then filter list based on the departments. Maybe the way to approach this is to join the 2 list and then filter by current username. I was thinking it would be faster to have the list of departments to filter vs joining.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this question is even vaguely related to XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a [filter web part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-a-filter-web-part-to-a-data-view-web-part-HA010250997.aspx)?